# slack-ruby-botでactive_support (LoadError)になる

Tags: ruby, rubygems, wsl

以下のslack-ruby-botを使用しようとしましたがエラーとなります。
https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-bot

Ruby自体もRails Girls（https://railsgirls.jp/install ）を参考に入れたばかりです。

実行した内容はslack-ruby-botのA Minimal Botで、

- Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'slack-ruby-bot'
gem 'async-websocket', '~>0.8.0'
```

- pongbot.rb

```
require 'slack-ruby-bot'

class PongBot < SlackRubyBot::Bot
  command 'ping' do |client, data, match|
    client.say(text: 'pong', channel: data.channel)
  end
end

PongBot.run
```

```
$ bundle install
$ slack-bot$ SLACK_API_TOKEN=API文字列 bundle exec ruby pongbot.rb
```

■詳細なエラー内容

```
マシン名:~/ruby/slack-bot$ SLACK_API_TOKEN=APIを記載 bundle exec ruby pongbot.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
        9: from pongbot.rb:1:in `<main>'
        8: from pongbot.rb:1:in `require'
        7: from /home/ユーザー名/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/slack-ruby-bot-0.16.0/lib/slack-ruby-bot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        6: from /home/ユーザー名/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/slack-ruby-bot-0.16.0/lib/slack-ruby-bot.rb:3:in `require'
        5: from /home/ユーザー名/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/slack-ruby-bot-0.16.0/lib/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        4: from /home/ユーザー名/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/slack-ruby-bot-0.16.0/lib/config/environment.rb:5:in `require'
        3: from /home/ユーザー名/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/slack-ruby-bot-0.16.0/lib/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from /home/ユーザー名/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/slack-ruby-bot-0.16.0/lib/config/application.rb:6:in `require'
        1: from /home/ユーザー名/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/slack-ruby-bot-0.16.0/lib/config/boot.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ユーザー名/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/slack-ruby-bot-0.16.0/lib/config/boot.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support (LoadError)
```

■解決のために試したこと
エラー内容にactive_supportがロードできませんとあるためirbでそれ自体をrequireしてみるとOKとなりましたのでファイル自体はあるようです。

```
irb(main):001:0> require "active_support"
=> true
```

■環境
WSL2
rbenv 1.1.2-34-g0843745
Ruby 2.7.0
Gem 3.1.2
Bundler version 2.1.2

何かご存知の方がいればご回答いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slack-ruby-botがactive_supportを使っているのにその設定を消してしまったのが原因のようです。
↓すでにプルリクエストも出ているので少し待てば解決するとは思います。
https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-bot/pull/271

一時的には以下のようにactivesupportの記述をGemfileに追記すれば解決するかと。

```
gem 'slack-ruby-bot'
gem 'async-websocket', '~>0.8.0'
gem 'activesupport'  # <= この行を追加
```

なおirbではactivesupportが読み込めたのにslack-ruby-botの起動ではエラーになっていた件ですが、`bundle exec` を付けて実行した場合は `Gemfile`と`Gemfile.lock` に書かれたライブラリしか読み込まないため、記述のない `active_support` のロードに失敗してしまったのが原因です。

Comment: ありがとうございます、slack-ruby-bot自体の問題だったのですね、確かにgemfileに追加したところ上記のエラーは出なくなりました。ただ、「 `on_complete': not_allowed_token_type (Slack::Web::Api::Errors::NotAllowedTokenType)」という新しいエラーが発生してしまいました･･･。slack-ruby-bot自体の修正を待つのが賢明でしょうか･･･。

Comment: `Slack::Web::Api::Errors::NotAllowedTokenType` とあるので `SLACK_API_TOKEN` で渡してるトークンがおかしいのかも?

Comment: トークンがおかしいかもということで許可する権限を全部有効にしてみたりしましたが、結果どうも現在のSlackのアプリに対応していないようでした。https://api.slack.com/apps?new_classic_app=1 にてクラシックAppを利用すると動作しました。助かりましたありがとうございました。